# Override a form field value in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**Note:** I was overthinking things when I originally asked this question. The accepted answer is correct for the examples I gave - i.e. you can just pass `:value` to text_field, however I'd actually been having problems with `date_select`, which doesn't have a facility to override the value set.

As a result this has now been updated in Rails, so you can set `:selected => a_date`, and it will work as expected. This will be in Rails 4.

---

I have a model that can inherit its value from a parent model. It works something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_name

  belongs_to :company

  def field_name
    if self['field_name'].nil?
      company['field_name']
    else
      self['field_name']
    end
  end

end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_name
end
```

I then have a form to edit the User, but of course, if the User value is nil, then it populates the form with the value from Company, which is not what I want.

I would like to be able to override the value of the form field, so that if the User value is nil, then the value is empty.

**Attempt 1**

Ideally I'd be able to do:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :field_name, @user['field_name'] %>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work, there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for providing an override value.

**Attempt 2**

So I thought about creating a second getter/setter:

```
def field_name_uninherited
  self['field_name']
end

def field_name_uninherited=(value)
  self['field_name']=value
end
```

Now I can use `<%= f.text_field :field_name_uninherited %>` and it works as expected - great! **Except:** when `field_name` is a date, or other type using multiparameter attributes, it results in this error:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

I believe this is because it doesn't know that this is a date field, as it infers this from the database, and this field (with _uninherited suffix) is not in the database.

*So I need some way to mark my additional method as the same type as the original database field.*

---

A further note, the above examples (using field_name) are a simplified version. I'm actually using https://github.com/colinbm/inherits_values_from to handle the inheritance, but I don't think this is important to the question.

---

Obviously if there's a better way to accomplish the same goal, then I'm all ears.

Comment: I think digitalWestie's solution is the way to go here. But for Attempt 2 I wrote a gem ages ago which let you have 'typed' attributes that weren't database backed, and I have just found out that someone ported it to Rails 3 (https://github.com/daemon/virtual_attributes) could be worth a look.

Comment: n.b. just spotted that it's 2 years old, so you might not want to _actually_ use it, but might be of interest anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, that does look like the way to go doing it that way, but if I can keep it simple then I shall! Stuck on making that work on date_selects at the moment though (which is why I thought value: didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So when it comes to displaying the value you for a user you want it to behave a bit differently?

What I'd do is use the `:value` option with your form field. That way you get to set the value like normal but choose what you want displayed in the form field.

```
<%= f.text_field :company, :value => user.field_name_uninherited %>
```

Comment: Or just :value => user['field_name']

Comment: @digitalWestie Ah, so I have been completely over-thinking it! I had attempted to use this before, and it hadn't appeared to work. It looks like some extra magic is needed to make it work for date_select though... have tried `'2012-06-01'.to_date`, and  `{ 'field_name(1i)' => 2012, 'field_name(2i)' => 6, 'field_name(3i)' => 15 }`  and neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, you want the user to put the field data and only if it's nil, populate that value with the parent (company) model. It seems to me `before_save` works perfectly, because it is called (as it name proposes) just before the save method is called on an ActiveRecord object.
Thus you can write this kind of callback:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :field_name

      before_save :override_field

      private
        def override_field
          if self.field_name.nil?
            self.field_name = company.field_name
          end
        end
```

This way, you'll be only overriding the value if it's nil at the moment of saving, leaving that form field empty at the moment of creating a new element. Hope this works!

Comment: Not quite. The storage of the value in the User model should be unaffected. If no value is given then it should remain nil. When accessed, if it is nil, then the parent (Company) value should be returned instead (this bit's already working). The User shouldn't automatically have its value filled with the Company value.